# Getting Assertion error , when asserting json response value with datasource

Tags: json, groovy, soapui, assertions

I'm Asserting my Json response values with my database and but I'm getting assertion error.

Here is groovy script:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
// DataBase Properties
def DBcaseID = context.expand('${DataSource#CaseID}')
def DBDescription = context.expand('${DataSource#Description}' )

def row = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["DataSource"].currentRow
def CasesResponse = context.expand( '${Cases#Response}' )
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(CasesResponse)

//Response Values
def CaseID = json.Root[row-1].CaseID
def Description = json.Root[row-1].Description

assert CaseID == DBcaseID, "DB value: ${DBcaseID} is not equals to JSONResp value: ${CaseID}"
assert Description == DBDescription, "DB value: ${DBDescription} is not equals to JSONResp value: ${Description}"
```

Error log:

```
ERROR:An error occurred [DB value: 5 is not equals to JSONResp value: 5.  Expression: (CaseID == DBcaseID). Values: CaseID = 5, DBcaseID = 5], see error  log for details
ERROR:An error occurred [DB value: 4 is not equals to JSONResp value: 4. Expression: (CaseID == DBcaseID). Values: CaseID = 4, DBcaseID = 4], see error log for details
```

Even CaseID field values are same in database and json response

Comment: What are the return types of each attribute, are you sure that they are the same type/class?

Comment: DBcaseID is a string and CaseID is a integer , that's why getting error.

Comment: @Geeta then simply transform CaseID to string or if it's more accurate for your case because your ids will be always a number do the other way around and convert DBcaseID to integer: `assert CaseID == Integer.parseInt(DBcaseID)`.

Comment: Hope this is resolved using @albciff hint.

Comment: @Rao , I have already resolved this issue after Daniel Monti comment. Anyway thanks :)